# ¿Cómo obtener solo los números que estan entre caracteres en java?

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-netbeans

tengo un metodo que obtiene un campo llamado observaciones, este metodo se ejecuta al ingresar un valor el numero del formulario en un dialog y luego hace una llamada a un procedimiento almacenado que esta en sqlserver el paramtro enviado desde el dialog es el numero del formulario, lo que pasa es que el numero de formulario y el codigo del cliente están concatenados junto con algunas palabras en el campo observaciones, mi duda es como puedo obtener solo el numero del formulario 38532 y el codigo del cliente 720 y asignarla a una columna alguien podria ayudarme por favor

```
  Dialog ch = new Dialog(
            this,
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            "JTextField",
            "Atención",
            "Ingrese el número del Reporte de Control",
            Control.getColors(),
            Control.getIcon()
    );
    ch.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ch.setSize(400, 200);
    ch.setSoloNúmeros(true);
    ch.setVisible(true);
    if (ch.getEstado()==true) {
        nuevo(panelFormularios); 
 String ingreso = ch.getResultado().toString();
        Object[] parametros = new Object[1];
        parametros[0]=ingreso;
        String[] datos = Control.obtenerDatos("SQL2K8", "AmanecerProduccion", "proc_listar", parametros);
        if (datos.length>0) {
            String[] datosDesarmado = datos[0].split("-");
        
            String formulario= datosDesarmado[1].trim();
            String cliente = datosDesarmado[1].trim();
            String factura = "0";
            try {
                factura = datosDesarmado[5].trim();
                if (factura.equals("")) {
                    factura="0";
                }
            } catch(Exception e){}
            Dialog ch2 = new Dialog(
                this,
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                null,
                "Datos Obtenidos",
                "<html>Formulario: "+formulario+", Cliente: "+cliente+"<br/><center>¿Desea continuar?</center></html>",
                Control.getColors(),
                Control.getIcon()
            );
```

}

La consulta que quiero extraer es esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El metodo tambien utiliza otro metodo que se encuentra en una clase llamada control y sirve para obtener datos y llamar a los procedimientos en la variable datos estaria lo que se obtiene en la llamada al procedimiento proc_listar

```
   public static String[] obtenerDatos(String server,String db,String procedimiento,Object[] parametros) {
    String[] values=null;
    try (Connection conn = Conexion.conectar(server,db)) {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        int cantidad = parametros.length;
        String p="(?";
        for (int i=0;i<cantidad-1;i++) {
            p+=",";
            p+="?";
        }
        p+=")";
        try (CallableStatement pro = conn.prepareCall("{call "+procedimiento+p+"}")) {
            for (int i=1;i<=cantidad;i++) {
                pro.setObject(i, parametros[i-1]);
            }
            pro.execute();
            try (ResultSet rs = pro.executeQuery()) {
                ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                int columnas = md.getColumnCount();
                values=new String[columnas];
                while (rs.next()) {
                    for (int i=0;i<columnas;i++) {
                        values[i]=rs.getString(i+1);
                    }
                }
            } 
            conn.commit();
        } 
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Archivo.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        System.out.println(ex);
        DesktopNotify.showDesktopMessage("Error", "No se pudo obtener datos del procedimiento "+procedimiento+"\n"+ex, DesktopNotify.ERROR);
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: ¿que tiene "datos"?

Comment: **datos = Control.obtenerDatos**  en esta linea llama a un metodo **obtenerDatos**  en la clase control

Comment: me refería a un ejemplo de que información se obtiene

Comment: este es un ejemplo de lo que obtiene **Devoluciones - 38532 J Y C FERRETERIA 720** el codigo que intento es separar y obtener solo los numeros por ejemplo 38532 en una variable formulario y 720 en otra variable cliente

Comment: datos es un array (String[] datos), que valores tiene ese array?

Comment: **Devoluciones - 38532 J Y C FERRETERIA 720** seria este único valor que se guarda asi mismo en una columna llamada Observaciones ya se guarda concatenado el procedimiento lo unico que recupera es ese columna Observaciones

Answer (score 1):

En estos casos para que tu código funcione,es importante que la información tenga la misma estructura, con base en esto, puedes realizar lo siguiente para obtener la información.

```
String información = "Devs - 38532 FERRETERIA 720";

String inicio =  información.substring(información.indexOf("- ")+1).trim() ;
    String dato1 = inicio.substring(0,información.substring(información.indexOf("- ")+1).trim().indexOf(" ")) ;
    String dato2 = información.substring(información.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
    
    System.out.println("dato 1 :  " + dato1);      
    System.out.println("dato 2 :  " + dato2);
```

Salida:

```
dato 1 :  38532
dato 2 :  720
```